# 7 Bluetooth devices in a small area, interference?

Tags: bluetooth, interference

Is having 7 Bluetooth mice, each connected to a different computer, in a 15 by 15 foot room going to cause interference issues? LAN party coming up.

Answer (score 2):

There would be some form of interference but not enough to disrupt your LAN party

Comment: Not going to disrupt? Not so much of a good idea?

Comment: @Tobu im not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean I can understand your reply to mean two opposite things.

Comment: @Tobu sorry my answer has been edited to be more clear